# Is there an AND syntax for Github search?

Tags: github

Does Github's search feature have an AND feature, like:

stars:>0 && stars:<4

Comment: oh sorry, my original example was an artifact of tests.

Comment: I don't think your first statement is true.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your intent. What you're looking for might be provided by using the `..` search operator [explained here](https://github.com/blog/1328-search-syntax-improvements). Try a search using `stars:1..3` for your example (and using `1..3` because it's inclusive). I'm not sure if that covers all of your search scenarios, though.

Comment: Pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to `AND` together multiple conditions on the same parameter then it sounds like you're effectively trying to establish a range of some kind (like a number of stars between 0 and 4 in your example). While GitHub doesn't, to my knowledge, allow you to combine less/greater than expressions, there is an explicit range operator, the `..`, which is outlined a bit [here](https://github.com/blog/1328-search-syntax-improvements). You could use it like so:

```
stars:1..3
```

Note that for your specific example (stars:>0 && stars:<4) we need to use `1..3` because the range operator is inclusive. Using `stars:0..4` would give you repos with 0 stars or 4 stars, which the less/greater than combination would not.